# Restrict access to creating users on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL and would like to have only admins have the ability to create new users. While allowing some non-admin users read-write access to our tables.

I cannot find a way to get this done. I have a role called `webuser` to which I gave:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO webuser;
```

But now `webuser` has access to call `CREATE USER` and `GRANT ROLE` also. How can I remove access from `webuser` to do user-management operations while allowing `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` on our database tables?

Comment: That grant does most definitely **not** grant the `createuser` privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user can only create other users if it has the `createrole` property: this property is not assigned by default when creating a user.

[Doc.](http://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) says:

> CREATEROLE NOCREATEROLE
>
> These clauses determine whether a role will be permitted to create new roles (that is, execute CREATE ROLE). A role with CREATEROLE
> privilege can also alter and drop other roles. If not specified,
> NOCREATEROLE is the default.

Either the user has been created with `createrole` or a superuser has run: `alter user webuser createrole`.

To revoke that privilege run `alter user webuser nocreaterole`

NB:

> CREATE USER is now an alias for CREATE ROLE. The only difference is
> that when the command is spelled CREATE USER, LOGIN is assumed by
> default, whereas NOLOGIN is assumed when the command is spelled CREATE
> ROLE.